# React Query: Keep using cached resource on error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-query

I'm using the React Query framework.
Would it be possible to have useQuery return the content of the cache for a resource that was previously fetched but now came back with a 4** or 5** http status?

The idea would be to avoid showing no data or errors when the network (or server) is flaky for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, that should work out of the box. If you once got successful data for a query and then get another error, status should be `error` and both the `error` and `data` fields should be filled (data with the stale data from the previous fetch)